# Returning just only 1 line. However I have a more than 1000 lines. How can I solve?

Tags: python

**

```
def reading_file(rf):
      f = open(rf,'r')
      print('Rentable Houses İnformation:')
      for line in f.readlines():
          datas = line.split(',')
          c = datas[1]
          a = datas[2]
          r = datas[3]
          hoa = datas[9]
          ra = datas[10]
          pt = datas[11]
          fi = datas[12] 
          house_info = np.array((c,a,r,hoa,ra,pt,fi))
          print(*house_info,sep=',')
    f.close()
```

**
*I try to define a function that reads a file then assings all datas to an array. However, I cannot find the use of return. Because of not using return, this function also prints 'None'. Therefore my program do not work effectively. How can I solve this help me?*

Comment: Start with your question first. Then show your code. Somebody (not me) voted down your question. In my experience this often happens when the quality of the question is perceived low (which could happen owing to variety of reasons). All you needed here is _"how to write a python function with a return statement?"_

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You could use `numpy.genfromtxt()` to first load-in the data as an array and then select only the columns you need by specifying `column_indices`.

```py
import numpy as np

column_indices = [1,2,3,9,10,11,12]
# fname is the reading-filename.
a = np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter=',')[:,column_indices]
```

However, if you just want to return the result from your custom-defined function, you need to add a return statement as follows:

```py
def reading_file(rf):
    # define an empty list
    house_info = []
    # your code here
    # ...
    # for line in f.readlines():
        ...
        # append to the list for every pass in the loop
        house_info += np.array((c,a,r,hoa,ra,pt,fi))
    # list-to-array conversion
    house_info = np.array(house_info).reshape((len(house_info), 6))
    return house_info
```

Comment: wat do you want to mention? There is nothing to solve this code or numpy.genfromtxt() is another way to solve this. Whot do you mean? Cannot I fix this code as ı want ?

Comment: If you must, use a **`return`** statement as I showed. But otherwise, use numpy-native functions as they will process much faster in most of the cases.

Comment: I tried to use return function as you showed above. However it could not work. Again it prints out just 1 line

Comment: Updated solution. Your `house_info` was getting re-written in every pass of the `for` loop. Check now, it should work. But, the way you are trying to do this looks a bit clunky. I would still suggest you to use `numpy.genfromtxt()`.